# Android Google MapView Persisting Itemized Overlay onPause

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers, android-maps, itemizedoverlay

When working with Android Google MapView, how can I get the Itemized Overlay (multiple markers) to persist when I move into a Pause state.  I understand how to use onSaveInstanceState, but how does one do this on an overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do nothing when the application goes on Pause or even if it goes on Stop states. Both states preserve the activity memory and the overlay with all the information is still available for the activity. You may need to call mapView.invalidate() to have the screen redrawn.

If the activity go on Destroy state (ex. when you rotate de screen) then you need to save the overlay.

Here you have 2 main options:

1-If you are restarting your activity (i.e. due to a screen rotation) and want to preserve the overlay information or starting a new activity and you want to transfer the overlay indormation, you may use "Parcelable". I believe Itemized overlay doesn't support it directly, but you may extend it. It's very fast and quite easy.

2-If you want to preserve the information for a later use, then you need to save the information in a database or any other type of file.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It also thought it should stay and wasn't sure as to why.  Come to find out, I had the overlay creation in the onStart() function within a fragment, which means when I resumed I just created another (empty) overlay which caused my problem.  However, given if I had a specific situation, I feel your answer would have been best.